# Is there any way to avoid loading XMP metadata in iText 7?

Tags: c#, pdf, .net-core, itext7

I have a PDF file with a huge amount of xmp metadata. When I use itext7 to process it, the program is stuck in the statement `var pdfdocument origpdf = new pdfdocument (pdfreader);` Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet), I found that the open (null) method was executed in the constructor of Pdfdocument object, and finally stuck at `reader.pdfaconformancelevel = pdfaconformancelevel.getconformancelevel (xmpmatafactory. Parsefrombuffer (xmpmetadata));` and there is no option to avoid it, the xmp metadata is useless to me.

With itextSharp, base on [Remove XMP Metadata on PDF/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31529496/remove-xmp-metadata-on-pdf-a), I can get a pdf file without metadata.

```cs
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
PdfDictionary dict = reader.Catalog;
dict.Remove(PdfName.METADATA);
dict.Remove(PdfName.PROPERTIES);
reader.RemoveUnusedObjects();
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(target, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite));
stamper.Close();
```

I tried to create a subclass of PdfReader or PdfDocument, to try to interfere with loading metadata, but all failed.

Use itext7, Is there any way to avoid loading metadata? Or is there any way to Remove XMP Metadata?

Comment: Hi, can you attach the PDF file to reproduce the problem?

Comment: [testfile](https://1drv.ms/b/s!AqxJcIfHZ18Udj5wtfWl8aJSepc?e=J19mN8).Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can override `PdfReader` and skip reading metadata objects. In fact, the objects are read, but we the reader will behave as if there is no metadata and it will not tell anyone that it is present.

Custom `PdfReader` implementation:

```
private static class MetadataFreePdfReader extends PdfReader {
    public MetadataFreePdfReader(String filename) throws IOException {
        super(filename);
    }

    @Override
    protected PdfObject readObject(PdfIndirectReference reference) {
        PdfObject obj = super.readObject(reference);
        if (obj instanceof PdfStream && PdfName.Metadata.equals(((PdfStream) obj).getAsName(PdfName.Type))) {
            // skip metadata object
            return null;
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
```

This is how you pass the overloaded instance to `PdfDocument`:

```
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new MetadataFreePdfReader("C:/path/to/140mmX90mm-2000BGJCV1M.pdf"));
```