# How to use same form template on every page in IText 7

Tags: java, pdf, itext7

I have a pdf template which contains images and form fields.
I read this template and fill form fields per page and write to a temp pdf file. Then I read this file and copy to a master document to have multiple pages using the same template. Roughly as below:

```
Document masterDoc = ...

 -- loop per page --
PdfWriter pfdWriter = new PdfWriter(tmpFileName); 
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(templateFile), pfdWriter); 
Document doc = new Document(pdf);

// Set form fields
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdf, true);
form.setDefaultJustification(0);
Map<String, PdfFormField> formFields = form.getFormFields();
formFields.get("key").setValue("value");
form.flattenFields();

doc.close();

try (PdfDocument resource = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("pathToTmpFile"))) {
    resource.copyPagesTo(1, 1, masterDoc.getPdfDocument());
}
-- end of loop
```

This approach is slow (depends on the template file size, but takes seconds not milliseconds).
Would it be possible to use same template file per every page without writing and reading from/to temp files?
I read the documentation and guess it might be possible with new page event handler but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Have you tried using in-memory streams (`ByteArrayInputStream` and `ByteArrayOutputStream`) instead of file streams? If you have enough memory available, this might improve performance.

Comment: I was already working on it and it definitely helped. Still would have been nice to have a template per page feature.

Comment: @mkl as I see most of the time is spent while opening the pdf document and specifically on below methods: com.itextpdf.kernel.xmp.XMPMetaFactory.parseFromBuffer, com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.XmpMetaInfoConverter.appendMetadataToInfo. Any suggestion on how to improve on those?

Comment: Two ideas: **(A)** Also keep the template in memory, reading it once into a `byte[]` and initializing the `PdfReader` instances from that array. **(B)** As a preparation step remove the XMP metadata from the source PDF.

Comment: @mkl could you point me on how to achieve option B? I tried the custom reader in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60904873/895348 but ended up with: Caused by: com.itextpdf.io.IOException: Invalid offset for object 3 0 R. Do I need to provide an XMP after using the custom reader?

Comment: I have overwritten the readPdf method and removed the metada and it seems to be working. But not sure if I have broken anything or if it has any side effects 
    `@Override
     protected void readPdf() throws IOException {
      super.readPdf();
      if (this.trailer.containsKey(PdfName.Root)) {
       PdfDictionary root = (PdfDictionary) this.trailer.get(PdfName.Root);
       root.remove(PdfName.Metadata);
      }
     }`

Comment: At first glance that approach makes sense. The only side effect should be that you don't have root metadata. That the solution from the referenced answer does result in an exception indicates, though, that there is some issue in the PDF itself.

Comment: @mkl thank you for all the help! Performance is better now with your suggested changes.